# Rust aes 128 decrypt ecb error InvalidLength

Tags: rust, aes

```
fn encrypt(key: &[u8], text: &[u8]) -> Result<Vec<u8>, symmetriccipher::SymmetricCipherError>  {
    let mut encrypt = crypto::aes::ecb_encryptor(
        KeySize128,  //
        key,
        PkcsPadding,
    );
    let mut read_buffer = RefReadBuffer::new(text);
    let mut result = vec![0; text.len() * 4];
    let mut write_buffer = RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut result);
    encrypt.encrypt(&mut read_buffer, &mut write_buffer, true).unwrap();
    Ok(result)
}
```

```
fn decrypt(key: &[u8], text: &[u8]) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut decrypt = crypto::aes::ecb_decryptor(
        KeySize128,
        key,
        PkcsPadding,
    );
    let mut read_buffer = RefReadBuffer::new(text);
    let mut result = vec![0; text.len()];
    let mut write_buffer = RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut result);
    let fina=decrypt.decrypt(&mut read_buffer, &mut write_buffer, true);
    match fina{
        Ok(fa)=>info!("succ"),
        Err(e)=>info!("{:?}",e)
    }
    Ok(result)
}
```

When I try to encrypt the short content, the encryption and decryption are successful, but when I encrypt the long string, the encryption succeeds and the decryption fails.

```
Err(e)=>info!("{:?}",e)
```

print  InvalidPadding

When encrypting and decrypting a long string, the encryption succeeds and the decryption fails. However, when I decrypt the encryption result in Java, it succeeds

Comment: Please show the encryption function as well. It sounds like the encryption function might be truncating its output.

Comment: I edited and added the encryption method. When the decryption error occurs, the Java decryption method is successful

Comment: You're skipping _all_ null bytes from the output of the encryption?

Comment: Yes, or it will fill in my blank. Does this have any effect? I am correct when encrypting short strings

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. There may be nul byte padding at the end, but there can also be valid nul bytes in the middle of the encrypted blob, too. You're stripping them all out, when _theoretically_ you could get away with only stripping the trailing ones. It's like saying "periods are implied at the end of a paragraph, so I'm going to strip out all periods in a paragraph" -- okay but what about periods after sentences within the paragraph, or in abbreviations? You're removing those, too, and they're important.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Now what I want to encrypt is that there is no null bytes in the key string of RSA

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I can guarantee that the encrypted result is correct, because it can be successfully decrypted through the Java decryption method, and an error(InvalidLength) will be reported when decrypting in trust

Comment: That's not necessary true, Java might just be more lenient about malformed encrypted payloads.

Comment: I can guarantee that the encrypted result is incorrect in the general case because if there is a zero in the middle you removed it. I can only assume that the Java function you use adds zero-padding to reach the correct length and that you are lucky in that your encrypted data doesn't have internal zeroes.

Comment: I see what you mean. I modified the encryption method. Now there are new problems There will be errors（InvalidPadding） in decryption

Comment: Probably because there is leftover space in the output buffer that you don't properly truncate. Try `result.truncate(write_buffer.position());` right before you return `Ok(result)`. You should probably also assert that the result of your `.unwrap()` call on the encryption result isn't `BufferResult::BufferOverflow`, otherwise it ran out of space to put encrypted data.